# in golang go/src/time.go, why daysPer100Years = 365*100 + 24?

Tags: go

I'm reading golang source code of `package time`
And I got some constants like:

```golang
// file: /usr/local/go/src/time/time.go
const (
    secondsPerMinute = 60
    secondsPerHour   = 60 * secondsPerMinute
    secondsPerDay    = 24 * secondsPerHour
    secondsPerWeek   = 7 * secondsPerDay
    daysPer400Years  = 365*400 + 97
    daysPer100Years  = 365*100 + 24
    daysPer4Years    = 365*4 + 1
)
```

I'm wondering why

```golang
daysPer400Years  = 365*400 + 97
daysPer100Years  = 365*100 + 24
```

but not

```golang
daysPer400Years  = 365*400 + 100
daysPer100Years  = 365*100 + 25
```

Answer (score 1):

When I'm typing this question, I got the answer myself  ----

Usually we call a year X is a leap year if X is divisible by 4. While the year X is divisible by 100 but not divisible by 400, we say X is not a leap year.

That means, every 100 years, there are at least 24 leap years. Among the 100 years, there is a year which must be divisible by 100, but may not be divisible by 400, this phenomenon occurs by the probability of 3/4. In other words, every 100 years, the probability of 24 leap years is 75%, and 25% for 25 leap years. That's why

```golang
daysPer100Years  = 365*100 + 24
```

Every 400 years, there must be 3 years which can be divisible by 100 but not divisible by 400.
That's why

```golang
daysPer400Years  = 365*400 + 97
//that is : daysPer400Years  = 365*400 + (25 * 4 - 3)
//     or : daysPer400Years  = 365*400 + (24 * 4 + 1)
```